# Do not call Dispose of parts in dispose MEF

Tags: c#, containers, mef, dispose

I ran into a problem when the application ends the container does not call the Dispose method of the parts.
Application based on MEF.

When I explicitly call Dispose the container, then matod Dispose is called on the parts, but if you just close the program, the Dispose of the parts will not be called, why?
How to make sure that when you close the program were caused by the Dispose method of all parts of the container MEF?

```
[Export(typeof(IMyClass))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class MyClass: IDisposable, IMyClass
{
    private bool disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(!this.disposed)
        {
            if(disposing)
            {
                // Dispose managed resources.

            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your 'Parts' shouldn't need Dispose on program-exit.

Comment: For example, the section contains a thread, not background, and this thread should be the correct way to stop, how do you have to do that?

Answer (score 2):

> When I explicitly call Dispose the container, then matod Dispose is called on the parts, but if you just close the program, the Dispose of the parts will not be called, why?

Because disposing the container when you are done with it is mandatory. If your program does not call CompositionContainer.Dispose() before exiting, then that is a bug in your program.

Answer (score 0):

**Wim Coenen**, thanks, I thought that the destruction of MEF must call Destruct on parts.
I made ​​sure to work the way I need to:

```
public partial class MyBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
   public MyBootstrapper()
   {
      App.Current.Exit += new ExitEventHandler(Current_Exit);
   }

   void Current_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
   {
      if (this.Container != null)
         this.Container.Dispose();
   }
...
```